# Blocking read from stdin in python

Tags: python, io, stdin, blocking

How to perform a blocking read operation from stdin in python (2.7) that pauses process until some data appears in the pipe?

The problem with `read()` lies in the fact that after the first time it returns, `read()` does not block anymore. Example:

`echo 'test test ' | python test.py`

```
# test.py
import sys
while True:
  string = sys.stdin.read() # Blocks only for the first time
  print '!!!!!!!!'
```

Comment: `pipe` sends text `test test` to script and closes connection - what do you expect to read with next `read()` ?

Comment: Another process (e.g. parent) can write into stdin of this process.

Comment: as for me parent process can write only to `echo`, not to script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f.read()` blocks, but also returns an empty string if EOF is reached. Your example is broken, since the input stream is closed and EOF is reached. Also you most likely wanted to read an entire line, so `readline` is appropriate.

Comment: Mb you know, is there a way to fix stdin after eof reached ?

Comment: There is no way. Your question sounds a lot like the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) though, it may help if you state your actual problem (in a new question)

Comment: The problem has different solutions (e.g., using some other interprocessing tools), I just thought that I can handle it fast with the direct approach. The original problem is a wrapper for syntaxnet docker container that does not need to be restarted on every input (starting time is substantial). It can process data from stdin and it seems quite complicated to make internal script to read something else.